# How to programatically determine whether iOS app is from app store or has been copied to device during development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios

I have some debugging code that I want to run when my app is either running in the simulator, or running on a development device (with or without debugger attached).  I don't want this debugging code to run when the app is running on a device after being downloaded from the app store.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Note: The above-mentioned code will be in a library that will be used by other developers, so I would prefer to use some code that I can embed in this library, without requiring any further action from the developers using the library.

Although my library is a C# library (Xamarin.iOS), any Objective-C, Swift, or Xamarin.iOS answers would all be useful.

Comment: Hopefully the version and/or build number is different and can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

When you're running it on the simulator or in Xcode, you can set the Scheme to debug and just put if-statments in. When it runs from the store it won't be in debug mode unless you've hard coded that somewhere.

To answer your question directly: No you're not able to detect the apps source (App Store Vs Xcode deployment) as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DEBUG` macro, it's defined in Objective-C projects for debug builds. But better way is to use your own macro to enable additional logging. Add information about this macro to docs and developer will decide to enable logging or not by defining it in his project. Also how to set preprocessor macros I described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749177/4185345).